# Why Node.js doesn't stop?

Tags: node.js

It's widely known that Node.js keeps track of all the work requests and doesn't stops if there are requests in this table. And is there a method to get a list of this requests to recognize why Node doesn't want to stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can find answer [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1128).

You can use `process._getActiveHandles()` to see all handles (active timers and etc.) and `process._getActiveRequests()` to get info about libuv requests.